# How can I check if a URL on Amazon S3 is valid, and not expired using ruby

Tags: ruby, http, amazon-s3

I need to accept a url like:
`https://aidin.s3.amazonaws.com/appname/bucket/folder/faxattach/bXs9FerLJR1tnhs3z?AWSAccessKeyId=ACCEDD_KEY&Expires=1372360744&Signature=SIGNATURE`

and check if that URL is valid, and not expired.

I've tried a few different things, but they tend to error out. For example:

```
url = URI.parse("https://aidin.s3.amazonaws.com/appname/bucket/folder/faxattach/bXs9FerLJR1tnhs3z?AWSAccessKeyId=ACCEDD_KEY&Expires=1372360744&Signature=SIGNATURE")
req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
res = req.request_head(url.path)
```

This gives me
`Net::HTTPBadResponse: wrong status line: "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"` whether or not the URL is valid or not.

Comment: are you trying to find out if there is a specific asset is available on s3?

Comment: @fenec More that the url actually points to a valid asset (not expired)

Comment: why are you adding the AWSAccessKeyId and all the other parameters? you don't need those, it is probably why you are having the wrong status line!!

Comment: Comes with the link I get

Answer (score 1):

Just ran up against this myself, this is what fixed it for me:

```
url      = URI.parse(url_param)
http     = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

http.use_ssl = true if url.scheme == 'https'

response = http.request_head(url.path)
```

The wrong status line is due to the Net library treating the request as HTTP when S3 can be either. The `use_ssl` boolean assignment is conditional on the scheme being HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the aws-s3 gem (https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3)

```
S3Object.exists? 'headshot.jpg', 'photos'
```

Comment: Trying to make it an API so it can accept any pdf instead of just something hosted on S3